# Difference between cycle basis and fundamental cycle basis

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

In graph theory what's the difference between cycle basis and fundamental cycle basis?

The problem is that I have an example in the book and there are matrices of both types of basis, and I don't know why are they different. I'm looking for some kind of thesis or definition that indicate this difference strong.

Thanks you very much.